# Update tags in Azure Mobile Services from Cordova App

Tags: cordova, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, phonegap-pushplugin

I am developing an App that is to run on iOS and Android using the cordova framework. The underlying system exposes a particular functionality to users, that to subscribe and unsubscribe from a list of some 20 categories. Everytime the user does a subscription/unsubscription the Azure registration needs to be updated.

At the moment I am doing this by re-registering but I would like to know whether there is a way to just update the tags and not re-register completely.

For some reason my current method of re-registration is not working properly: when changing some categories and re-registering: say I was subscribed to cat1,cat2,cat3 and now I am subscribed for cat1,cat4,cat5, in some instances I still receive notifications for cat2 and cat3.

Instead of getting lost in trying to figure out the reason why the above is happening, I am trying to go a step back, and find a way that does not require re-registration but rather a 'tag' update: perhaps using the 'right' method will also get rid of the problem.

This is how I am currently registering:

```
if (platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android') {
            // Template registration.
            var template = '{ "data" : {"message":"$(message)"}}';
            // Register for notifications.
            mobileServiceClient.push.gcm.registerTemplate(handle,
                'myTemplate', template, categoryarray)
                .done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
        } else if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
            // Template registration.
            var template = '{"aps": {"alert": "$(message)"}}';
            // Register for notifications.            
            mobileServiceClient.push.apns.registerTemplate(handle,
                'myTemplate', template, categoryarray)
                .done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underneath the registration, the process does an update-or-create operation that just does the update for the tags.  You can have a singular template that covers all platforms.  Re-registering is thus the "right thing" to do here.